# Gradient Fill in Swift for iOS-Charts

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I am trying to create a nice gradient fill as seen in the demos on the ios-charts page.  However, I cannot figure this out in swift vs obj-c.
Here is the obj-c code:

```
NSArray *gradientColors = @[
                    (id)[ChartColorTemplates colorFromString:@"#00ff0000"].CGColor,
                    (id)[ChartColorTemplates colorFromString:@"#ffff0000"].CGColor
                    ];
CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(nil, (CFArrayRef)gradientColors, nil);

set1.fillAlpha = 1.f;
set1.fill = [ChartFill fillWithLinearGradient:gradient angle:90.f];
```

Now here is my version of that in swift:

```
    let gradColors = [UIColor.cyanColor().CGColor, UIColor.init(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.0)]
    let colorLocations:[CGFloat] = [0.0, 1.0]
    let gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), gradColors, colorLocations)
```

What I am missing is the :
Chart Fill fillWithLinearGradient

I can't find the fillWithLinearGradient in the pod anywhere so I am a bit confused.

Thanks in advance for any help!
Rob

Comment: Check out the implementation of ChartFill: https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts/blob/607c4515d92b9fa5b15192981c3cc4f8bb38f01b/Charts/Classes/Utils/ChartFill.swift
There's an init that accepts a linearGradient and angle.
I believe @matt's answer to be correct.

Comment: @Stephen, in the LineChartDataSet class there is no .fill.  However there is a fillFormatter but clearly in my noobish state, I am not sure how to make that work.

Comment: `LineChartDataSet` is a subclass of `LineRadarChartDataSet`.
`LineRadarChartDataSet` does have a public fill variable, so it should be available to you.

Comment: Hi, sorry I have the same question and in your code what does set1 stand for?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This works perfectly *(Swift 3.1 and ios-charts 3.0.1)*

---

```
let gradientColors = [UIColor.cyan.cgColor, UIColor.clear.cgColor] as CFArray // Colors of the gradient
let colorLocations:[CGFloat] = [1.0, 0.0] // Positioning of the gradient
let gradient = CGGradient.init(colorsSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), colors: gradientColors, locations: colorLocations) // Gradient Object
yourDataSetName.fill = Fill.fillWithLinearGradient(gradient!, angle: 90.0) // Set the Gradient
set.drawFilledEnabled = true // Draw the Gradient
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: How to get curved effect in graph ?

Comment: @KiritVaghela I don't remember exactly, you'll have to check the documentation to find that. (https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts)

You may need to use the `cubic` option or a `bezier` option.

Comment: @KiritVaghela 
yourSet.mode = .cubicBezier //  smooth line chart

Comment: I am new to charts...how to implement this code with line charts?

Answer (score 8):

For **Swift 5** use the following:

```
yourDataSetName.fill = LinearGradientFill(....
or
yourDataSetName.fill = ColorFill(...
```

More details you can read here:
[Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/blob/master/Source/Charts/Utils/Fill.swift)

Comment: Updated recently and had an error with this. These classes fixed it for me.

Answer (score 6):

I believe this is the code that you are looking for. You should be able to use the same `ChartFill` class in Swift to set `set1.fill`.

```
let gradColors = [UIColor.cyanColor().CGColor, UIColor.clearColor.CGColor]
let colorLocations:[CGFloat] = [0.0, 1.0]
if let gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), gradColors, colorLocations) {
    set1.fill = ChartFill(linearGradient: gradient, angle: 90.0)
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I did not think to put that in { }.
However, when I use ChartFill the error I get is: 
unresolved identifier 'ChartFill'

Comment: it should be ChartFill.fillWithLinearGradient(...)

Comment: Hi, what does set1 stands for?

Comment: @VAAA: set1 was just a variable name in this example.

Answer (score 3):

**For swift4**

```
let colorTop =  UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 149.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
let colorBottom = UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 94.0/255.0, blue: 58.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor

let gradientColors = [colorTop, colorBottom] as CFArray
let colorLocations:[CGFloat] = [0.0, 1.0]
let gradient = CGGradient.init(colorsSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), colors: gradientColors, locations: colorLocations) // Gradient Object
yourDataSetName.fill = Fill.fillWithLinearGradient(gradient!, angle: 90.0)
```

Comment: it appears you also have to add `yourDataSetName.drawFilledEnabled = true`

Answer (score 2):

**Fill.fillWithLinearGradiant** has been updated to **LinearGradientFill**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use the latest version of ios-charts. If you use CocoaPods to install ios-charts change this:

`pod 'Charts'`

to this

```
pod 'Charts', '~> 2.2'
```

Comment: I just had to wait for that rev I guess :) I still don't get the gradient fill but at least the error doesn't rear its ugly head.  Thank you.

Comment: @throb you probably have solved it already, but just in case: I copy pasted your code and didn't get gradient either, and turns out the issue was that the second color was not sent in as .CGColor. Adding this solved it for me.

  let gradColors = [UIColor.cyanColor().CGColor, UIColor.init(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.0).CGColor]

Comment: Sweet!  Thanks!  I ended up not using the gradient but I will now :)  Cheers!!