# Bar chart with Gradient: iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, charts

Any Idea of giving gradient colors in Bar Chart of "https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts"

Comment: Did you check LineChart (gradient fill) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `CGGradientCreateWithColors`

Have a look at the answer from this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35133314/gradient-fill-in-swift-for-ios-charts)